# How to get an eager loaded conditional to be lazy loading later on with ActiveRecord and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, lazy-loading, eager-loading

First let me show some code.

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  named_scope :employees, { :conditions => ["roles.name = 'Employee'"], :include => :roles }
end
```

OK, so later in a controller I wanted to search for all the employees right. I set the named scope up to help do that with the join and conditional search. But the problem is in the view I want to show all of that users roles, but It will only display the employee role.

Is there anyway that I can say "user.roles" and have the be lazy loaded in the view after I have already eager loaded it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`habtm`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001792) (as well as `has_many`) states that you can access the collection with an optional parameter:

> collection(force_reload = false)
>
> Returns an array of all the associated objects. An empty array is
>   returned if none are found.

You can reload the roles with `user.roles(true)`.

Comment: You sir are fantastic. I never knew that existed. Guess I should have read the documentation a little more thoroughly.

Thanks for the good answer!